# Multiple custome date format for one column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can we put up a OR command for custom time in one column?
I have multiple time formats in one column of excel. For eg:

```
Timing
30 min
31 sec
4 min 20 sec  
1 hr 2 min
3 hr
1 hr 23 min 30 sec
```

I want to convert it to time format: `hh:mm:ss` so that i can calculate average from all times. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: I tried with adding custom formats in excel but it seems one column adheres to one custom format at a time.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need VBA to do this using a macro.

Comment: Isn't there any other simple alternative?

Comment: You'll need to get the data with a complex formula using Trim, Replace, ifs with ands and probably some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shorter formula:

```
=TIME(IF(IFERROR(FIND("hr";$A2);0)=0;0;IFERROR(MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("hr";$A2);0)-3;2);MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("hr";$A2);0)-2;1)));IF(IFERROR(FIND("min";$A2);0)=0;0;IFERROR(MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("min";$A2);0)-3;2);MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("min";$A2);0)-2;1)));IF(IFERROR(FIND("sec";$A2);0)=0;0;IFERROR(MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("sec";$A2);0)-3;2);MID($A2;IFERROR(FIND("sec";$A2);0)-2;1))))
```

Note: the above formula contains semicolon (;) as a separator. Replace with coma (,), in case this is your system separator.

To be honest I did not try to decipher @Foxfire's formula.

Remember to apply custom time format to the result cell: **[h]:mm:ss**
[image: custom format]

For explanatory reasons see breakdown of the long formula:
[image: breakdown]

Comment: Sorry but I think [h]:mm:ss is not supported in the excel which I use. Moreover I was getting error near "hr" in your formula.

Comment: What do you mean by not supported? [Read this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/266691/how-to-sum-and-format-a-range-of-hours-minutes-or-seconds-in-excel)

And what error do you get?

Comment: It just shows there is a problem with the formula and brings marker at "hr".Will you be able to share with me your sheet ? maybe Gdrive?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/179PbSneq7INUUFJ2Mzq8Fp-9eg5PyMaB/view?usp=sharing) it is :)

Comment: @kajalp, I've rejected your edit and added a comment related to system separator used in formula. Both are correct: (;) and (,). It depends on system settings :)

Answer (score 0):

This huge formula worked for me:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)>0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)=0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)&" 00 sec";" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)=0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)>0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("00 hr " & TRIM(A1);" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)=0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)=0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)&"00 min 00 sec";" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)=0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)=0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("00 hr " & TRIM(A1)&" 00 sec";" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("hr";A1;1);0)=0;IFERROR(FIND("min";A1;1);0)=0;IFERROR(FIND("sec";A1;1);0)>0);TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("00 hr 00 min "&TRIM(A1);" ";"");"hr";":");"min";":");"sec";"");"hh:mm:ss");"Formula needs to be updated"))))))
```

As I said, you need to check every string in your text. Depending if it contains `hr,min,sec`, you need to calculate the time and then convert it to time. Also, you need to take care of those annoying blanks at end of some strings. This formula does all this.

[image]

Hope you can adapt this to your needs. My Excel is in spanish, but I translated formulas manually. Just in case I typed wrong, I uploaded a file example to Gdrive for you to download and check the formulas (they should autotranslate if you open it).

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13J5IWLOFFZpzvIp1oqPwqkE3eHDk7EeH

Comment: I dont know why but I am getting output like :
30 min hh:30:00

Comment: How is the value you used? Make sure the cell you are apllying the formula has the right format.

Comment: I have used time format for output cell. I just downloaded your sheet and the ouptut is shown for all the cells in hh:<minutes>:<seconds>. Example: 1 hr 2 min hh:02:00

Comment: In the file i provided, results are shown exactly as my screenshot. What are you trying to do now?

Comment: I am using excel 2016, maybe version has to do something with output, not sure.